# Pip dependency issue : error: httplib2 0.15.0 is installed but httplib2<0.10,>=0.8 is required by set(['apache-beam'])

Tags: python, pip, httplib2

when trying to install python project,  python setup.py  install
I get the error,

```
error: httplib2 0.15.0 is installed but httplib2<0.10,>=0.8 is required by set(['apache-beam'])
```

However, looking at the pip dependencies

```
    Imrans-MacBook-Pro:appengine imran$ pip freeze | grep httplib2
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution -ix 1.13.0 (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-ix==1.1'": Expected W:(abcd...)
WARNING: Could not generate requirement for distribution - x (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages): Parse error at "'-===x'": Expected W:(abcd...)
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
httplib2==0.9.2
```

Could you please let me know from where it is taking the version 0.15.0, and why it is not using 0.9.2 instead ?

Comment: There's not enough information here to know the answer. Please start a new virtualenv, install the requirements, and post the full output of that pip install.

Comment: Tom, thanks for the comment, created new virtualenv, but results are the same. Any ideas? (env) ip-192-168-0-101:appengine imran$ pip2 freeze | grep http
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.3
httplib2==0.9.2
(env) ip-192-168-0-101:appengine imran$

Comment: Fastest way to solution is show setup.py and full terminal output.

Comment: Please start a new virtualenv, install the requirements, **and post the full output of that pip install**.